# Issue Connecting to Mssql Instance From Google Cloud Function

Tags: python, sql-server, google-cloud-platform, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to connect to a mssql instance in cloud sql in a cloud function. I have gone through the necessary steps of setting up a private IP, serverless VPC connector, and connecting my function to the VPC. I have been able to connect to the instance in nodejs but python suits my current needs more. The error I'm getting in the logs is:

> pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'

From all the examples I have read it does not appear that you need to import them or anything.
This is my process of connecting and executing a simple request.

```
import sqlalchemy
import pyodbc

def hello_world(request):
        # connect_simple()
        db = connect_tcp_socket()
        a = execute_request(db)
        return a
    
def connect_tcp_socket() -> sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:
    db_host = 'my_private_ip'  
    db_user = 'my_db_user'
    db_pass = 'my_db_pass'
    db_name = 'my_db_name'
    db_port = 'my_db_port' 

    connection_string = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+db_host+';PORT='+db_port+'DATABASE='+db_name+';UID='+db_user+';PWD='+ db_pass+';Encrypt=no'
    connection_url = sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        connection_url
    )

def execute_request(db: sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine):
        print('ok')
        with db.connect() as conn:
            result = conn.execute('SELECT @@VERSION')
            barray= []
            for row in result:
                barray.append(row)
        return barray
```

Comment: IIRC that error is because you don't have the SQL Server driver on the machine you're trying to connect from. So you need to install the SQL Server driver on the machine. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16 Check the docs there for installing the SQL Server driver on Linux. You'll need to do something like that in the container set up.

Comment: @GabeWeiss Please correct me if I'm wrong but I thought that gcp function took care of libraries like that. I have been using [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/connect-functions) guide and there is nothing about adding the ODBC library for sql server. Please let me know if there is a resource I am missing.

Comment: I COULD be wrong, but I've had this problem with SQLAlchemy before with any of the 3 db engines. If the operating system doesn't have the right drivers/libraries it (SQLAlchemy) can't instantiate the engine properly. JUST for grins and giggles, add a build step to your container: `pip install sqlalchemy-pytds` and see if that solves the issue. If that works let me know and I'll write up a quick answer to the question with that as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using the [Cloud SQL Python Connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector) to connect to Cloud SQL from Python as it will not require the ODBC driver and is much easier to use within Cloud Functions/Cloud Run.

Just replace your `connect_tcp_socket` with the below `connect_with_connector` function.

```py
from google.cloud.sql.connector import Connector, IPTypes
import pytds

import sqlalchemy

def connect_with_connector() -> sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:
    def getconn() -> pytds.Connection:
        with Connector() as connector:
            conn = connector.connect(
                "project-id:region:instance-name",  # Cloud SQL connection name
                "pytds",
                user="my-user",
                password="my-password",
                db="my-database",
                ip_type=IPTypes.PRIVATE
            )
            return conn

    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        "mssql+pytds://localhost",
        creator=getconn,
    )
    return engine
```

You can find a [code sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/main/cloud-sql/sql-server/sqlalchemy/connect_connector.py) for the Python Connector similar to the one you are using for establishing a TCP connection.

**Note:** Pytds driver is not super great with error handling. If you see the `OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor` error it usually means your database user is missing proper permissions and should grant them the necessary grants from a root user.

Your `requirements.txt` should include the following:

```
cloud-sql-python-connector
SQLAlchemy
python-tds
sqlalchemy-pytds
```

There is also an interactive getting started [Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector/blob/main/samples/notebooks/sqlserver_python_connector.ipynb) that will walk you through using the Python Connector without you needing to change a single line of code!

It makes connecting to Cloud SQL both easy and secure from Cloud Functions.

Comment: I have tried this method but am getting that OSError. I am using the default sqlserver user that is created when the instance is created. Are you referring to database level permission? Is there anything else this error could be referring to? @JackWotherspoon

Comment: If you are using the default `sqlserver` user then you should be fine since that user has root level permissions. One thing to try is to "edit" your Cloud Function and double check the VPC connector is attached in Connections-> Egress settings, sometimes this resets and unattaches your VPC Connector. Also check the box for "Route only requests to private IPs through the VPC connector" for some reason that setting works best.

Comment: It turned out to be a mistake on my end. Thank you I have marked your answer as correct! @JackWotherspoon